# WebLogic 12c classpath location + sqljdbc42 driver?

Tags: azure, sql-server-2014, weblogic12c, ssi, sqljdbc

I am not able to find the WebLogic CLASSPATH variable in either of these two files - commEnv.sh and commEnv.cmd. I do not understand where to add sqljdbc42 nor how to connect to an Azure SQL Server Database (is that even possible)?

I downloaded sqljdbc42.jar from MSDN and added it to my $DOMAIN/lib but where is the CLASSPATH; I do not see one to modify. As I understand, I need to add the path to the JAR.

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\common\bin

commEnv.cmd - no classpath:

```
IF NOT DEFINED MW_HOME (
 IF NOT DEFINED WL_HOME (
  echo MW_HOME or WL_HOME is not set
  IF DEFINED USE_CMD_EXIT (
   EXIT 1
  ) ELSE (
   EXIT /B 1
  )
 )
)

IF NOT DEFINED MW_HOME set MW_HOME=%WL_HOME%\..
FOR %%i IN ("%MW_HOME%") DO SET MW_HOME=%%~fsi

CALL "%MW_HOME%\oracle_common\common\bin\commEnv.cmd"
```

commEnv.sh - no classpath:

```
if [ -z "${MW_HOME}" -a -z "${WL_HOME}" ]; then
 echo "MW_HOME or WL_HOME is not set."
 exit 1
fi

if [ -z "${MW_HOME}" ]; then
  MW_HOME="${WL_HOME}/.."
fi

. "${MW_HOME}/oracle_common/common/bin/commEnv.sh"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I got it to work by completing the following:

- Major and minor versions have to be supported and synchronized. That is to say, you must use sqljdbc4.jar in your project class path and place a copy of that jar in $DOMAIN/lib for Oracle WebLogic, where $DOMAIN for me was `C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\lib`. There were no other files in this directory, but if you read the readme.txt it will tell you that **you do not need to modify the classpath.** For me, looking into commEnv.cmd or other such files, there was no classpath at all. The specific error I received was:

  ```
      java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
  com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
  ```
- I used the link below to help me install sqljdbc in Maven, so I can add the needed dependency in my POM file: http://techmajik.com/2014/04/24/how-to-setup-maven-dependency-for-microsoft-sql-server/
- Optionally, I added the below piece of code to invoke the driver. Many answers here recommended it and even pointed to scenarios where creating a connection will not work without it.

  ```
  try {
          Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  ```
- I was on an Azure SQL Database. This is important as there is an additional step - firewall settings must be properly configured from the Azure dashboard. I used the below MSDN guide to help me perform these steps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuresqldbsupport/archive/2015/04/29/configuring-the-firewall-for-client-access.aspx